# Copy/ Paste from spatial attribute tables into non-spatial tables in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, table

Imagine I have a shapefile which has its own attribute table and I have a non-spatial stand alone table too. I am going to copy the rows from the shapefile attribute table into the stand alone table but when I start editing on the table and copy the features from the shapefile attribute table, paste doesn't work and I can't copy the values inside the stand-alone table.
I was wondering if there is a way to copy and paste only the values of spatial attribute tables rows (and obviously not the spatial data) into a non-spatial table in Arcmap.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you are asking? It sounds like all you need to do is export from the Attribute Table view.

Comment: Added more info for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I think you are asking:

1) Open the Attribute Table

[image: Step1]

2) Export the table to a new table

[image: Step2]

3) Save the type of table you want in a location you want

[image: Step3]

4) Edit the new table all you need

5) Join the new table to the old and

6) Calculate the new field values in the old table from those in the joined new table

[image: FieldCalcStep]

Comment: Could we just join the attribute table without exporting it? and also for joining the new table to the old one, since we don't have any record in the new table how do we manage to join it?

Comment: Ans to 1st Q: Not without a key field.   Ans to 2nd Q: Exporting the shapefile attribute table automatically generates a key field (FID) for later joining the new table to the old.